# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function distance() on null

Tags: php

i have class Car, and here i have a method which caт calculate destination from point to point.
But this method in other class, in class Point.

Point:

```
<?php
    class Point {
        private $x;
        private $y;

        public function Point($x = 0, $y = 0) {
            $this->x = $x;
            $this->y = $y;
        }

        public function getX() {
            return $this->x;
        }

        public function getY() {
            return $this->y;
        }

        public function setX($x) {
            $this->x = $x;
        }

        public function setY($y) {
            $this->y = $y;
        }

        public function distance($other) { // method which calculate destination
            return hypot($this->x-$other->x, $this->y-$other->y);
        }

        public function __toString() {
            return sprintf("(%g, %g)", $this->x, $this->y);
        }
    }

    function compare($x, $y) {
        if ( $x == $y ) {
            echo $x . " is equal to " . $y . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            echo $x . " is not equal to " . $y . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    function diff($x, $y) {
        if ( $x === $y ) {
            echo $x . " and " . $y . " the same" . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            echo $x . " and " . $y . " different" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

?>
```

Class Car: (Which doesnt work)

```
<?php  

include "Point.php"; //include Point

class Car {
    private $location;
    private $model;
    private $fuelAmount;
    private $fuelCapacity;
    private $fuelConsumption;
```

Constructor

```
    public function Car( $capacity = 60, $consumption = 0.5, $location = null,$model = "Walkswagen") {
        $this->fuelAmount = $capacity;
        $this->fuelCapacity = $capacity;
        $this->fuelConsumption = $consumption;
        $this->location = $location;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function getFuelAmount() {
        return $this->fuelAmount;
    }

    public function getFuelCapacity() {
        return $this->fuelCapacity;
    }

    public function getFuelConsumption() {
        return $this->fuelConsumption;
    }

    public function getLocation() {
        return $this->location;
    }

    public function getModel() {
        return $this->model;
    }

    public function drive($destination) { //problems in this method
         if ( $this->location == null) {
             throw new ZeroLocation();
         }
         $distance = new Point();
        $fuelNeeded = $this->location->distance($destination) * $this->fuelConsumption;
            if ( $this->fuelAmount < $fuelNeeded ) {
                throw new OutOfFuel();
            }

            $this->fuelAmount -= $fuelNeeded;
            $this->location = $destination;
    }

    public function drive1($x, $y) {
        $point = new Point($x, $y);
        $this->drive($point);
    }

    public function refill($fuel) {
        if ($fuel > $this->fuelCapacity) {
            throw new ToMuchFuel();
        }
        $this->fuelAmount += $fuel;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return sprintf("Name of car : " . $this->model . PHP_EOL . "Fuel amount : " . $this->fuelAmount . " / " . $this->fuelCapacity);
    }
}

$car = new Car(60, 0.5, 3,3, "Walen");

$x = 50;
$y = 70;
$car->drive($x, $y);

$car->getLocation();

echo $car; 

?>
```

Compiler error :

```
Uncaught Error: Class "ZeroLocation" not found in PHP\Car\Car.php:42
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function distance() on null in PHP\Car\Car.php:45
Stack trace:
#0 PHP\Car\Car.php(75): Car->drive(50,
 70)
#1 {main}
  thrown in PHP\Car\Car.php on line 45
```

I have suspicions that the problem is in the initialization of the "location" field, because it must be of the "Point" type, but im not sure

Comment: You just instantiated a Point object in `$distance = new Point();` so its NOT `$this->location->distance(....` its simply `$distance->distance(...`

Comment: I understood correctly what needs to be changed to like this I understood correctly what needs to be changed to like this `$fuelNeeded = $distance->distance($destination) * $this->fuelConsumption;` ?@RiggsFolly

Comment: Well $distance is at least a value object of the correct type :)

Comment: i asked cose i changed but nothing fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think, instead of check the location property like above, you can try this one:

```php
if (!($this->location instanceof Point)) {
    throw new ZeroLocation();
}
```

This will check both null status and the property type. You initialized a new Car object with the third param is the "3" number, this is not a Point instance.